# Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found. but now sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

this was my problem at first,i searched and found a page the said remove and  reinstall.
i used these commands:

```
sudo apt purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

now when i type :sudo service mongod start

i get :sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This error actually has nothing to do with MongoDB and would happen for many commands, it's because you've actually deleted the directory your terminal is currently opened for. For example, if you did this:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
rmdir .
service blah blah
```

Also explained via this [Unix Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477872/error-sh-0-getcwd-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-when-i-try-to-upgrade-de/477938)

Comment: i would like to know about the first error that is Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

Comment: That means the service doesn't exist. The name might have change, try typing just `mongo` and using TAB to complete the name. It might be called something like `mongod-communtiy` or `mongod-server` or something else.